# Setting up Cron.yaml in Google App Engine to work with files in Google Cloud Bucket. (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I am using the Google App Engine to host a flask website.
*Standard environment
Python with flask app*

Basically, I have a `main.py` that has the script the public website runs on.
I now want to create a separate tasks.py script to run the jobs I need to do daily at a scheduled time. For trials, I am trying to delete a file currently in my bucket. `main.py`, `app.yaml`, `cron.yaml`, and `tasks.py` are NOT inside the static folder. Many answers in stack are now old (2012 etc) and I literally do not know how to troubleshoot crontask errors in the google app engine.

**Directory system**

- main_workspace

  ```
     - main.py

     - app.yaml

     - cron.yaml

     - tasks.py 

     - static 

     - templates
  ```

app.yaml

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 0

env_variables: 
(not revealed here, but used and works for main.py)

handlers: 
  - 
    static_dir: static
    url: /static
  - 
    static_dir: stylesheets
    url: /stylesheets
 
 -
    url: /tasks.py
    script: auto

  

runtime: python37
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "daily summary job"
  url: /tasks.py
  schedule: every 1 minutes from 21:32 to 00:00
```

tasks.py

```
from google.cloud import storage

def delete_blob(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Deletes a blob from the bucket."""
    bucket_name = "pre_processed_bucket"
    blob_name = "rundata_AJA3_1_alyssa.txt"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.delete()

    print("Blob {} deleted.".format(blob_name))
```

The error looks something like this:

```
*2020-11-03 23:37:50.886 HKT GET 404 378 B
2.2 s AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) /tasks.py
 
0.1.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:23:37:50 +0800] "GET /tasks.py HTTP/1.1" 404 378 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "actalab-site.et.r.appspot.com" ms=2202 cpu_ms=2704 cpm_usd=4.2244e-8 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c61a968804f0ee2e09e312c75107ee9586a411dfa6c52433304ed11a0c18f55d08e78360d0aaf8815539460b9f603aec57e70dddb5a8af339ad5cfe314fdcd5f2cd11674fc1a34e75 app_engine_release=1.9.71 trace_id=a459042362528c52842c90b6f932f9e0*
```

Comment: Whats your `main.py` look like? Specifically, it'd be good to see the route in `main.py` you setup for `/tasks.py` thats supposed to call `delete_blob` in the file `tasks.py`. Second, are there more handlers in your `app.yaml` that you didn't include here? According to the `app.yaml` that you posted here, the only route that `main.py` handles is `/tasks.py`. Third, I'm worried that you think that naming the url of your route `tasks.py` will somehow hit `tasks.py`. Maybe you meant to set `script` in `app.yaml` to be `tasks.py`, because based on what you wrote, main.py should be calling tasks.py

Comment: The cron service is apparently trying to access `http://0.1.0.1/tasks.py` and your access log shows a 404.  Are you able to access the public version of that URL outside of cron?  Cron is just going to make an HTTP call on a schedule.  Ensure that you can execute that same GET request to your app.

Comment: My main.py is the python script for the main flask app. So, that is the entire script for the public website, dynamically controlling each page of my website (like submitting forms etc). 
But, I'm trying to make a separate python script that is within the same project but is not directly linked to the public website. Instead tasks.py should simply delete files in my Google Storage bucket, scheduled at a specific time each day by cron task. 

Does this make sense? So, I don't want main.py to be involved in the cron jobs. How do I get the cron job to execute tasks.py at scheduled times?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if you can do that via `app.yaml` in python3.

In python2 in your `app.yml`, you used to be able to set `script` on a handler entry to different python files.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref

But in python3, they dont allow that anymore. `script` can only be set to `auto` because all traffic is to be handled by what you defined in `entrypoint`
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup

#### Try editting `entrypoint`

You possibly could modify the call to `gunicorn` or use something else instead of `gunicorn` for entrypoint to allow you to send specific traffic to `tasks.py` instead of `main.py`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup

#### Separate micro-service

I think your best bet is to make `tasks.py` into a separate micro-service called `tasks_service`

```
main_workspace/
- tasks_service/
    - tasks_service.yaml
    - tasks_main.py
    - requirements.txt  # requirements for tasks_main.py
- main.py
- requirements.txt  # requirements for main.py
- app.yaml
- cron.yaml
- static/
- templates/
```

`tasks_service/tasks_service.yaml`

```
service: tasks_service
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT tasks_main:app --timeout 0
runtime: python37
```

`tasks_service/tasks_main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import storage

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/cron/delete-blob/', methods=['GET'])
def delete_blob():
    """Deletes a blob from the bucket."""
    bucket_name = "pre_processed_bucket"
    blob_name = "rundata_AJA3_1_alyssa.txt"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.delete()

    print("Blob {} deleted.".format(blob_name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

and then in `cron.yaml` specify `tasks_service` for `target` and update the url to `/cron/delete-blob/` as I defined in `tasks_main.py`:

```
cron:
- description: "daily summary job"
  url: /cron/delete-blob/
  schedule: every 1 minutes from 21:32 to 00:00
  target: tasks_service
```

Note that you will need to deploy this service in addition to your main service

`gcloud app deploy tasks_service/tasks_service.yaml --project your-project-id`